# Can't add Google Plugin for Eclipse to Eclipse for Java EE developers (Helios edition)?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, ganymede, helios

I just installed Eclipse Helios (Java EE edition) and tried to install the Google App Engine plugin for Eclipse.

I get the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5 1.3.3.v201006111302 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e35.feature.feature.group 1.3.3.v201006111302)
  Missing requirement: Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5 1.3.3.v201006111302 (com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.e35.feature.feature.group 1.3.3.v201006111302) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.5.0,3.6.0)' but it could not be found
```

Is it only possible to add the plugin to Ganymede - not Helios?

Comment: this is happening again for me: 3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a version of the GAE Plugin for Eclipse 3.6/Helios listed on [the Download page](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/download.html) - did you try this?